# Why is it that the Skull Knight and Void are against each other?

Tags: berserk

In the manga, the Skull Night foils many of the God's Hand's plans, and also attempts to kill Void specifically. Why did the Skull Knight do these things? Is there a past between Void and the Skull Knight? And what are his intentions as far as killing Void?

[image: The Skull Knight trying to hit Void]

Comment: The manga  hasn't revealed details about Skull Knight other than the hint that he once don the Berserker armor, has some relation with Flora, is enemy of Godhand and its followers, and was possibly the great king Gaiseric. A presumption has been given about the issue you raised: see the second point of trivia [here](http://berserk.wikia.com/wiki/Gaiseric#Trivia).